# How to set the MixMonitor extension that match the RTP codec used?

Tags: codec, asterisk

I have a dialplan where I am using the application MixMonitor. This application take a file path, and the extension is used to define the format of the file (wav, alaw, ulaw, g729, ...).

For the moment, I pass a .wav file path.

But I would like to have it match the codec used in the rtp that is recorded.

How can I retreive the codec in the dialplan ? I am using Asterisk 17, and pjsip. Using PJSIP_HEADER(read,X-Best-Codec) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CHANNEL function with following params:

```
audioreadformat - R/O format currently being read.
audionativeformat - R/O format used natively for audio.
audiowriteformat - R/O format currently being written.
```